# Android MVVM UI-realated class size

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-mvvm, android-architecture

I'm working on a relatively big `Android` project. This project's app architecture is `MVVM`, and all layer responsibilities are separated well enough. Still, as this project is getting bigger, it's hard to maintain some, especially UI-related classes. I wonder if there is a better way to handle and shrink the UI class size in the number of code lines (nearly 2500 lines)?

- ex: `SinglePostFragment` contains all UI-related logic like ( file download status, file type behavior ( pdf, audio, image, video ), like, bookmark, share, showing suggested list as a horizontal list, comments, etc.).

Comment: 2500 is indeed too many lines for a single class. In your `SinglePostFragment` you can always **split** the logic depending on the functions you need for downloading files & its status, file type behaviour (split different actions depending on file types), etc. Showing suggested list & comments is something that can definitely be split up from the same Fragment to other use cases..

Comment: @DarShan can you explain more about "other use cases" in your comment, please?

Comment: Example like create a separate BottomSheetFragment & a helper to load/manage comments & other related actions. So instead of handling everything in the fragment, you could move the comments handling to other UI classes & helper/utils classes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't group code by it's type.
For eg. folders like ViewModels, Activities, Fragments etc.

You should group it by its functionalites like loginScreen,
homeScreen, chatScreen. Each part contains everything which
is requrired to run it. Also apis list can be distributed according
to it.

By the way this is also recomended by google for android development but not able to find it's link. Sorry about that.